# How did Python become popular as a scripting language?

Tags: programming-languages, python, history, scripting

I looked at it in my field of work, which is film and pretty much every software we use comes with python as a scripting language: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Python_software That made me assume it's the most popular.

How did Python become popular as a scripting language? Especially as an embedded language into standalone applications.

What's the reason for this? There are others like Lua, Ruby, etc. but yet it looks like Python came on top.

If it's because of a particular thing or just a matter of getting out there at the right time?

Comment: I could see this becoming a flame war

Comment: I seriously doubt that Python is more popular than ECMAScript, Perl, PHP and Bash.

Comment: I would try to answer this, but who's to say that Python is the most popular scripting language? What about Ruby, PHP, Perl, Smalltalk, R, etc.? This is a very subjective question. Voted to close.

Comment: "Python came on top" where did you get that? I thought MS DOS bat files are most "popular" "language", given amount of those writing these

Comment: I only looked at it in my field of work, which is film and pretty much every software we use comes with python as a scripting language: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Python_software That's why I assumed it's the most popular.

Comment: I think python is not a scripting language. At least not in the way Perl or sh is. Python is rather a *general purpose interpreted multi-paradigm programming language*.

Comment: "I only looked at it in my field of work, which is film" There's your problem: you are looking your subfield and assuming every other subfield is the same. I work in bioinformatics and Python is very popular there too. However, the number of people working in film or in bioinformatics is minuscule compared to the number of folks writing web applications where Javascript and PHP are ubiquitous. No question, Python is a very popular language, but if you want to start arguing about which is "most popular", you'll quickly be reduced to handwaving and boosterism.

Comment: Then maybe you should narrow the question to "how did Python become the most popular scripting language in the field of film?" In that case the answer is self evident: Autodesk supports it as a scripting language for Maya.

Comment: Not really, not all Autodesk apps have python as a scripting language. Besides Autodesk there are other major 3d apps that do support python so no it's not because Autodesk supports it.

Comment: Ruby being made in Japan probably delayed its spread. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/260896/how-much-did-ruby-being-created-in-japan-delay-its-spread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to say for certain, but in my experience most people I know who like python like it become of it's rich "batteries included" nature. It comes with an incredible number of modules that do many useful things, which means developers spend less time reinventing wheels and more time making interesting applications.

Answer (score 8):

In most cases, behind a successful language is a powerful sponsor.  AT&T gave us C and C++, Microsoft created the .NET family, Java came from Sun, and even though they didn't invent it, Apple is almost completely responsible for the recent popularity of Objective-C.  (Though that's a borderline case, since [pretty much nobody outside the OSX/iOS ecosystem is using Objective-C for anything](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178092/why-was-objective-c-popularity-so-sudden-on-tiobe-index).)

Python is the same way.  It was around for a long time, but it was a fairly obscure language until it found institutional favor at Google.  They decided they liked it so much that they ended up hiring Guido Van Rossum! And now Python's a really big language.

Comment: Python was already successful by 2000, when Google influence was about null.

Comment: You could also say that Google hired Guido because of the popularity of Python.

Answer (score 3):

Popularity of any language is difficult to measure. There is not a clear indicator that makes one language better than the other. The reason is that there is no language that is the most suitable for everything.

Some languages are more specialized for certain tasks even though they may be used for other tasks (Perl excels in string processing, PHP is famous a web serverside language, Fortran was popular for number crunching, ...).

The age of the language also influences popularity. Say, Fortran would not be that popular for number crunching if it was not one of the oldest (usefull) programming languages.

I like Python, but I would not dare to do an ultimate comparison with other languages. Anyway, I like its clean syntax, readability, brevity, pragmatism, pseudo-code look.

In my opinion, the languages could be compared only in pairs -- i.e. one language vs. the other. And it should be done by people who have intimate knowledge of both.